# Android Ndk: Uploading a Large File through NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to upload a file (20MB of size) but while uploading, logcat shows

> Out of Memory Exception

So I thought to use NDK for this. But i dont know how to proceed. So help me on this

```
static int chunkSize = 512;
static final     byte[] chunks = new byte[chunkSize]; 
.....
......
while (true) 
  {
    synchronized (chunks) 
    {
      int amountRead = fileInputStream.read(chunks);
      System.out.println("========amount read========="+amountRead);
      if (amountRead == -1) 
      {
        break;
      }
      bufferOutputStream.write(chunks, 0, amountRead);
      bufferOutputStream.flush();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you upload, you need to use an InputStream rather than loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: iam using "fileinputstream" to read and "byteoutputstream" to write

Comment: then perhaps yours HTTP upload methd is loading the whole byte array into memory

Comment: i had edited my question , with the snippet i have..plz Check and  y the error is coming

Comment: where is the byteoutputstream defined & used ?